# Migration from MySQL to Elasticsearch using Logstash

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to ELK stack. I am working with data migration from MySQL TO elasticsearch. I am following this tutorial:
https://qbox.io/blog/migrating-mysql-data-into-elasticsearch-using-logstash
and I have installed and configured MySQL and ElasticSearch. I could not configure Logstash.
I dont know where to find logstash.conf, so i created a file named logstash.conf in my conf.d file of logstash folder. I wrote the following in **logstash.conf**:

```
    input {

    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "root"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM authors"

    }
  }

    output {

       stdout { codec => json_lines }
       elasticsearch {
            "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
            "index" => "my-authors"
            "document_type" => "data"
    }
}
```

But when I run my command bin/logstash -f logstash.conf by going into /etc/logstash/conf.d folder from ubuntu terminal, It gives an error stating that bin/logstash does not exist.
Please help me with the issue.

Comment: Go into your logstash install folder and run this: `bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf` or simply `bin/logstash` and all config files present in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` will be used